# Spring batch flow declaration using java config

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-java-config

I am reading the spring batch documentation and stuck on [following part](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/step.html#split-flows):

There are provided following example:

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
        Flow flow1 = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow1")
                        .start(step1())
                        .next(step2())
                        .build();
        Flow flow2 = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow2")
                        .start(step3())
                        .build();

        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                                .start(flow1)
                                .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                                .add(flow2)
                                .next(step4())
                                .end()
                                .build();
}
```

But it is not explained what is happening.

as far I understand flow1 and flow2 are executed in parallel but what about step4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`step4()` is executed linearly after `flow1` and `flow2` returned.

Look at the [`FlowBuilder.SplitBuilder.add()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/builder/FlowBuilder.SplitBuilder.html#add-org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.Flow...-) javadoc :

> `public FlowBuilder<Q> add(Flow... flows)`
>
> Add flows to the split, in addition to the current state already
>   present in the parent builder.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `flows` - more flows to add to the split
>
> Returns: the parent builder

It returns the parent builder and not the current `SplitBuilder` object.
So it is not included in the flow split and so is executed sequentially.

To run the 3 flows in parallel :

```
 return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                              .start(flow1)
                              .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                              .add(flow2, step4())                   
                              .end()
                              .build();
```